# Checking if a process was spawned by cron

Tags: linux, cron

I'm trying to setup a script that shutdown a VM if no cron jobs are running. There will also be another script that starts the VM an hour before the next scheduled cron job.
To do this, the best approach I've found so far without meddling with the cron jobs itself is to use `pstree` and see if the `cron` process has spawned any processes. Is there any other way to figure this out? Also, are there any flaws with using `pstree` to figure out if cron spawned a process.

Answer (score 1):

Every process has a **parent process ID**, so you can look for those spawned by cron. If you know the **process ID** of `CRON` (on Debianoids it is in `/run/crond.pid`), you can look for `CRON`'s children with:

```
ps --ppid $(</run/crond.pid)
```

or use the return code of `ps` to shutdown the system:

```
PIDFILE=/run/crond.pid
if ! [ -f $PIDFILE ] || ! ps --ppid $(<$PIDFILE) >/dev/null; then
    /sbin/shutdown
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

> Also, are there any flaws with using `pstree` to figure out if cron
>   spawned a process.

Yes this is flawed, it is unreliable. Especially if cron were stopped or restarted, running jobs would get orphaned, but still run (depending on which cron implementation).  By itself, cron is essentially fire and forget.

Better would be for jobs themselves to keep track of state. Each could take out an flock or something, but that's annoying to code into each job.

Instead, consider a job system like systemd. systemd services keep track of running state, and can be tied to other units including system shutdown. Actually, also add timers and you may be able to replace cron.

Answer (score 1):

Switching ON a Linux PC can be less reliable than shutting it down.

"BIOS Wakeup"- BIOS has an easy-to-use wake-up scheduler, enabled and set as needed.
"Wakeonlan"- this involves sending a signal from a second computer to a device that you want to turn on.
"RTC"-Check that your kernel has support for RTC, if it supports execute the script below.

## !/bin/bash

sh -c "echo 0 > /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm" # Zero if any wake alarm alredy
sh -c "echo `date '+%s' -d '+ 60 minutes'` > /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm" # To wake machine after 60 minutes by setting alarm
shutdown -h now #Shutdown the machine